# How to create a datapoint object with a loop in JS?

Tags: javascript, object, while-loop

I would like to create this output in a JS while loop:

```
      dataPoints: [
    { x: 10, y: 10 },
    { x: 20, y: 11 },
    { x: 30, y: 14 },
    { x: 40, y: 16 },
    { x: 50, y: 19 },
    { x: 60, y: 15 },
    { x: 70, y: 12 },
    { x: 80, y: 10 }
  ]
```

When I put this

```
sdata[i] = accumulated;
```

Into my loop, it adds the entries like that:

```
Object {
1: 1500, 
2: 3005, 
3: 4515.016666666666, 
4: 6030.066722222222, 
5: 7550.166944629629
}
```

What do I have to put into the loop to create the output like at the beginning?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to describe your inputs, we have no idea what's hiding behind `accumulated`. Are `dataPoints` and `sdata` the same object?

Comment: Please re-state the question. It is currently very difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to push (x, y) points in an array. This is is how it should be done.

```
var sdata = []; // an array;
```

assuming that accumulated is a point it should have a structure like below

```
accumulated = { x: 10, y: 20};
```

Next is just create the points and push it to the array.

```
while(/*loop-condition-*/) {
    var accumulated = {
        x: xCurrent,
        y: yCurrent
    };

    sdata.push(accmulated);
}

//that's it.
```

sdata now has the output as desired